# remove parent if no list element has children

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my Website I have a list with different classes which maybe have content or not. If all of them are empty the whole container should be removed, but if one or more have content inside, nothing should happen.

Code Snippets:

```
<div class="fts">
    <div class="panel-heading">...</div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-16 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner">            
                    <h5>Heading 5</h5>
                    <div>...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-84 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-31 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-82 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-85 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-86 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-87 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-88 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-89 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=" bd-layoutbox-90 clearfix">
                <div class="bd-container-inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".bd-layoutbox-84, .bd-layoutbox-31, .bd-layoutbox-82, .bd-layoutbox-85, .bd-layoutbox-86, .bd-layoutbox-87, .bd-layoutbox-88, .bd-layoutbox-89, .bd-layoutbox-90")
    .each(function(){
        if($(this).has("h5").length == 0){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }               
    });
```

What's the problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It removes the parent immediately when one of the containers is found empty.  You should set a flag and remove after all have been checked.  I'll post in an answer.

Comment: I think this isnt right way for creating HTML elements which based on your data. You should create all elements with jquery append method dynamicly.

Comment: Which div is container here? The one has the class "bd-container-inner" ? or its parent?

Comment: I mean the `.fts` container.

Comment: There is no element ".fts". Can you check your HTML

Comment: `<div class="fts">` is the first line

Comment: So there will be multiple container? (i,e ".fts" elements) ?

Comment: Yes. There are ten ".fts" class container/elements.

Comment: Check the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35275604/3733816

Comment: Your link's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rework your logic a bit by creating a function, but here's a thought ..

```
var removethis=1;
$(".bd-layoutbox-84, .bd-layoutbox-31, .bd-layoutbox-82, .bd-layoutbox-85, .bd-layoutbox-86, .bd-layoutbox-87, .bd-layoutbox-88, .bd-layoutbox-89, .bd-layoutbox-90")
    .each(function(){
        if($(this).has("h5").length > 0){
            removethis = 0;
        }               
    });
if (removethis == 1) {
  // remove parent item here
}
```

Comment: Here's the problem that the container is not the only one. I have ten `.fts` container with different `bd-layoutbox-` inside... 

`if (removethis == 1) {
  $(".fts").remove();
}`

would remove all container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains selector to check any content there or not and then remove it. Below is the code

```
$('div.fts').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find('div[class*="bd-layoutbox-"] h5').length === 0) {
    $this.remove();
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6bh0d9yo/1/

Comment: Hmmm... in my script only `"bd-layoutbox-"` will be deletetd.

Comment: In my code, it is the .fts which does not have any content is getting deleted.